# 400 bad request while deploying to app engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

While deploying to app engine, I got this error message:

```
400 Bad Request 

Creating an index failed for entity_type:
"GeoLocationStat"ancestor: falseProperty {  name: "ZoomLevel"}
Property {  name: "GeoPt"  mode: 3}:
Permission denied for creating a search index
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently GeoPt and ZoomLevel datatypes were NOT the cause.

The root cause of this error message is Eclipse is unable to update datastore-indexes-auto.xml in WEB-INF\appengine-generated folder.

I delete the file and the deployment proceed just fine.  :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [issue11963#c14](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11963#c14) on the app engine issue tracker:

> Geo-spatial queries are a new feature currently under development, and
>   expected to launch as Alpha sometime soon. When it does launch, it
>   will be for a limited group of apps; during Alpha, only those apps
>   will have "permission" to use it, which is why you're seeing this
>   confusing error message now...the SDK development server does
>   currently support the feature. So it works locally, but not in
>   production.

Comment: k...so I removed the GeoPt type and change the ZoomLevel enum type to String, but still getting the same error when deploying.  They are like bad piece of gum that just won't go away.... ugh